# Python recursion facts

Tags: python, function, recursion

I need help knowing which of the following are TRUE in a recursive function in python

1. A recursive solution to a problem is always preferable
2. A recursive function calls itself
3. Each recursive call diminishes the size of the problem
4. A recursive function can have one or more base cases
5. A recursive function can have one or more recursive steps.

Could I please get an answer as to which of these are true. MORE THAN ONE can be correct.

This was one of my past papers in my subject but I couldn't get the right answer for 5 and I was wondering if that was true or false. This isn't for homework and I'm not asking to just get the answer but for a further understanding of recursive functions in python.

Thank you!

Comment: Homework problem in CS?

Comment: What specifically are you asking about? This is far too broad.

Comment: Why not ask the professor if it's not homework?

Comment: "This isn't for homework" - I struggle to believe that given the format of the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) A recursive solution has a few benefits. Generally it is more readable, and smaller in terms of lines of code. When it doesn't work, it's almost always harder to debug. It's usually preferable when it runs faster than a non-recursive solution (see merge sort).

2) By definition.

3) True -- the point of recursion is to reduce every problem to a base case which has a trivial solution.

4) Also true. See the implementation below:

```
def pow3(input):
   if input//3 is not input/3:
       return False
   elif input is 1:
       return True
   else:
       return pow3(input/3)
```

5) Based on the wording of the question, "one **or** more recursive steps", certainly true. Every recursive function must have a recursive step, and therefore every recursive function must have one or more recursive steps.

Feel free to ask any other questions below.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking in my past exam papers for this question and I couldn't get the right answer. I had an exam yesterday and I was wondering if this answer was correct or not but thanks to you I now know that I did!! I appreciate the reply :)

Comment: Just FYI since you're new to StackOverflow -- upvotes on an answer are always appreciated. Glad I could help!

Comment: Yeah I tried but I need more than 15 reputation recorded. Thank you so much

Comment: With respect to #2, how would you answer with respect to mutually recursive functions, neither of which calls itself directly?